# Returning Span from a Property With Unsafe and Fixed

Tags: c#, .net, struct, unsafe, value-type

I came across something very much like the below at work.  I have never worked with a C# codebase that makes such heavy use of structs before.

I have used fixed before to prevent the garbage collector from moving things while I work on something unsafe using pointers.  But I've never seen it used while taking a pointer and passing it to a Span like this and then using the Span outside of the fixed statement.

Is this okay?  I guess since Span is managed, once we pass the location to it, then if the GC moves the location of MyStruct, it should get the new location okay right?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct MyInnerStruct
{
    public uint InnerValueA;
    public uint InnerValueB;
    public float InnerValueC;
    public long InnerValueD;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct MyStruct
{
    public MyInnerStruct Value0;
    public MyInnerStruct Value1;
    public MyInnerStruct Value2;
    public MyInnerStruct Value3;
    public MyInnerStruct Value4;
    public MyInnerStruct Value5;
    public MyInnerStruct Value6;
    public MyInnerStruct Value7;
    public MyInnerStruct Value8;
    public MyInnerStruct Value9;

    public int ValidValueCount;

    public Span<MyInnerStruct> Values
    {
        get
        {
            fixed (MyInnerStruct* ptr = &Value0)
            {
                return new Span<MyInnerStruct>(ptr, ValidValueCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from the docs: *Provides a type- and memory-safe representation of a contiguous region of arbitrary memory.*  and *Span<T> is a ref struct that is allocated on the stack rather than on the managed heap* and as MyStruct is a struct as well it won't be on the heap either so no moving is involved is my assumption.

Comment: I think the 2nd part of what @rene said is important.
With heap types this would probably not be the safe way to go and would need an extra `GCHandle.Alloc`

Comment: Suffice to say this code is pretty dangerous, and is only safe if used only with local variables or parameters. GC will *not* deal with this correctly, `Span<T>` is only designed for locals and should not really be used in this fashion

Comment: @Charlieface It certainly doesn't strike me as obviously safe.  But why exactly would this not work well with MyStruct as a member of MyClass on the heap and the Span being used on the stack inside some function?  Once the managed Span is created pointing to the right location, and the gc moves MyClass (and MyStruct insides of it), won't the location referred to in the Span be updated also?

Comment: Possibly it would be safe, but `MyStruct` has no knowledge of its storage location so couldn't guarantee that. You should really do this from the containing object. You could also do this without `unsafe` using `return MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan<MyInnerStruct>(ref Value0, ValidValueCount);` although the same caveats apply: you need to be careful that you don't leak a stack pointer

Comment: @Clarlieface I like that.  I've never heard seen that one before.  But from https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/InteropServices/MemoryMarshal.cs, it looks like that is just implemented as ```public static Span<T> CreateSpan<T>(ref T reference, int length) => new Span<T>(ref reference, length);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the source code in .NET 6

```
public unsafe Span(void* pointer, int length)
{
    _pointer = new ByReference<T>(ref Unsafe.As<byte, T>(ref *(byte*)pointer));
    _length = length;
}
```

Your code:

```
fixed (MyInnerStruct* ptr = &Value0)
{
    return new Span<MyInnerStruct>(ptr, ValidValueCount);
}
```

I did some tests, and using the span like you did is always safe to do even when the PTR gets moved around by the garbarge collector.

I also tested to write to the `Span` after the ptr had been moved and the original object was still correctly updated.

The Span will always return the correct values because of the `ByReference`

Answer (score 2):

### This is unsafe

Returning a `Span<T>` from a method is, in the general case, unsafe. It works, as long as one guarantees that the object it references to does not get out of scope *and* is not moved. These conditions apply only to stack variables that live at most as long as the Span itself. With the above code, consider this example:

```cs
public Span<MyInnerStruct> Foo()
{
    MyStruct s = default;
    s.Value0.InnerValueA = 3;
    s.Values[1].InnerValueB = 4; // this is fine
    return s.Values; // Peng! We're returning a reference to s, which is illegal
}
```

With the use of a pointer to initialize the Span, the runtime will also lose all means of tracking the reference it points to. So if `MyStruct` is part of an object, you'll easily get a dangling reference after the next GC run. .NET 5.0 and above has a method `MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan<T>` that works around some of the issues, but it's use is still dangerous.

A detailed analysis of the problems with such a struct can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/iot/issues/1886). The discussed struct `ValueArray<T>` looks very similiar to the example given in the OP. In the end, the decision was to remove it from the code base, because it's use is just too dangerous.