# How does a Span survive garbage collection?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I'm pretty convinced that creating a Span from an array doesn't fix (in the sense of the `fixed` keyword) the underlying array, otherwise there wouldn't be a need for `Span.GetPinnableReference` and since the lifetime of a Span can extend over unboundedly many allocations and "forgets" of other objects this would likely be
a bad performance choice too.

How then does a Span survive Garbage Collection? My mental model of a Span was that it's two integers (address and length) with some lifetime constraints that help the runtime guarantee they are used safely (in the sense of the managed runtime). This can't be right, because the address integer would be useless after Garbage collection. This in turn makes me belief that the Span does, in some deep underlying hidden sense, have a reference to the original array, even though that contradicts everything you read about Spans.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Here's a question for your mental model...how would a Span survive the lifetime of the stack it is used in?

Comment: "[When the garbage collector performs a collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals), it releases the memory for objects that are no longer being used by the application. It determines which objects are no longer being used by examining the application's roots. An application's roots include static fields, local variables on a thread's stack, CPU registers, GC handles, and the finalize queue. " - a ref to the array is reachable from a root, so it's not GCed.

Comment: An adjustment to your mental model: it's actually not two integers but a [reference](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c34ccb11f4ccd4de0112c34f9ccd86a1a28d9905/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Span.cs#L29) and an integer. And the reference makes the underlying collection keep alive even if it is not in use anywhere else.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I think my problem is that I don't have a good model of what "a reference" means either, especially one to a single entry in an array. I mean, obviously it could be a tuple of (actual object, memoryOffset) but that's not it, right? I guess at this point in asking about meaningless implementation details I guess and I should just accept the semantics (which I do believe I understand) offered by ref fields.

Comment: @DavidL right, I think I had only thought of Spans traveling down the stack before

Answer (score 2):

`Span<T>` uses quite some magic of the runtime to work correctly. But logically, it does, in fact, just contain a reference to the original array (or stack memory, or unmanaged memory). It's just hidden deeply in the runtime.

The fields of `Span<T>` are:

```cs
public readonly ref struct Span<T>
    {
        /// <summary>A byref or a native ptr.</summary>
        internal readonly ByReference<T> _pointer;
        /// <summary>The number of elements this Span contains.</summary>
        private readonly int _length;
    }
```

The magic part here is `ByReference<T>`, an internal runtime struct with no visible implementation but lots of documentation about it's magic:

```cs
    // ByReference<T> is meant to be used to represent "ref T" fields. It is working
    // around lack of first class support for byref fields in C# and IL. The JIT and
    // type loader has special handling for it that turns it into a thin wrapper around ref T.
    internal readonly ref struct ByReference<T>
    {
        private readonly IntPtr _value;

        [Intrinsic]
        public ByReference(ref T value)
        {
            // Implemented as a JIT intrinsic - This default implementation is for
            // completeness and to provide a concrete error if called via reflection
            // or if intrinsic is missed.
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
        }

        public ref T Value
        {
            // Implemented as a JIT intrinsic - This default implementation is for
            // completeness and to provide a concrete error if called via reflection
            // or if the intrinsic is missed.
            [Intrinsic]
            get => throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

The actual implementation can't be written directly in C# (as of C# 10) but it would be something as simple as this, when T is a managed type:

```cs
    internal readonly ref struct ByReference<T>
    {
        private readonly ref T _value; // A reference to a variable of type T

        public ByReference(ref T value)
        {
            _value = value;
        }

        public ref T Value
        {
            get => _value;
        }
    }
```

Now of course you need to be extra careful when the referenced object would otherwise be ready for garbage collection to make sure this doesn't cause problems, but since the runtime is involved, it can track the reference and knows that `_value` is actually a pointer to a managed object. It can then move it around much like it would for an "ordinary" managed reference. Nothing needs to be done if the reference is pointing to the stack, since that one doesn't move.

The whole concept about the use of `Span<T>` can increase performance, but it *is* possible to write code that fools the runtime and causes dangling references, even if everything appears to be plain managed code, without any (explicit) `unsafe` references. See [here](https://github.com/dotnet/iot/issues/1886) for an instance of such a problem.

Comment: For the record, it can be and is written in C# in .Net 7: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Span.cs

Comment: @Blindy Oh, thank you for clarification. I thought this would come only in .NET 8.

Comment: So, in theory it is possible to retrieve the array from the span, at least for the runtime? And if I create a Span that points to the middle of another Span, both can still be linked to the original object?

Comment: If not, what DOES the runtime do to make sure the ByReference still points to the correct location after compaction?

Comment: Also, you say "it is possible to write code that fools the runtime and causes dangling references, even if everything appears to be plain managed code, without any (explicit) unsafe references" but the example you show has a very explicit `Unsafe.As` in it

Comment: @Bananach Yes. The runtime still knows how to track the reference (or at least it should). Technically, the runtime needs to keep track of _all_ references to objects anyway. Resolving the reference to an object (even if it doesn't point to its beginning) to the object itself isn't magic.

Comment: @Blindy now that it's written is there any more optimization and support in the runtime beyond what's in the plain source?

Comment: True, didn't remember that part (but it works without it, see further down in the issue). Also, a bit confusingly, the use of the `Unsafe` class doesn't require code to be marked `unsafe` in general.

Comment: @PMF Based on the examples further down the issue you posted, do you think the accepted answer to this question is wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70404914/returning-span-from-a-property-with-unsafe-and-fixed ?

Comment: @Bananach, you need to start being clearer about what version of `Span` you're talking about. For example, getting a `Span` in .Net Framework is *always* unsafe and every time you use it you roll the dice for a catastrophic runtime failure from which there is no return. The pre- and post-Net7 `Span`s are safe in the sense that the GC won't clear what you reference, that's a guarantee of the runtime. The .Net7 version is functionally identical, but uses newly introduced C# and .Net7 runtime mechanisms to support it directly.

Comment: That said, if you do something stupid like pinning an array and storing a span over the pointer, then the GC moves the array in memory after you unpin it, you'll obviously access the wrong memory. The runtime provides you with clear methods to reference a managed chunk of memory (arrays, individual objects, etc) without this downside, but you need to use them. If you use pointers, you are exactly what your method is: `unsafe`.

Comment: In other words, yes, the answer in that question is wrong. Pinning a pointer is unsafe, you need to pin the reference if it's a managed object.

Comment: @Blindy I'm talking about the .NET7 version

Comment: So with this version, I guess the question "how does the runtime know how to keep a Span valid during compaction" is equivalent to the question "how does the runtime know how to keep a 'ref T' field that refers to the middle of some array valid" to which I still don't think I'd know what to answer

Comment: Btw, it'd be nice if you corrected the answer there (via a comment or your own answer) i don't feel confident enough to do it myself, but you'd have my upvote

Comment: @Bananach Wrote an answer on the other question. Note that the example the question gives there is very similar to the `ValueArray<T>` issue described in my link.

Comment: I can't exactly say how they do it in the real runtime, but an easy implementation would just do this: Look at the pointer, see that it points to a block of managed memory and then go sequentially through that block to find the actual object into which the pointer points. (A block of memory is just a linked list of allocated objects)